# BrowseTags method (Collector object) | VBA vs C#

Tags: c#, vba, sdk, historian, proficy

For a while i've been trying to make a standalone program in c#, which uses the BrowseTags function from iHistorian_SDK. (iFix 5.8 and Historian 7.0)

First I made this function in VBA where it works great, but due to VBA being single threaded, I want to moive it out of VBA.

My VBA code that works today:

```
Public connectedServer As Object
Public myServerManager As Object


Private Sub TestBrowseFunction()    
    Call BrowseTagsFromHistorianCollector("SVNF-IFIX-HIS01", "SVNF-IFIX-SCA01_iFIX")    
End Sub

Public Function BrowseTagsFromHistorianCollector(ByVal HistServer As String, ByVal HistCollector As String, Optional AdditionsOnly As Boolean = False, Optional SourceFilter As String = "*", Optional DescriptionFilter As String = "*")
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim MyTags As Variant
    Dim Tag As Variant

    Set connectedServer = Nothing
    Set MyServerManager = CreateObject("iHistorian_SDK.ServerManager")
    DoEvents

    'Make sure Historian is installed correctly'
    If MyServerManager Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise 0, , "Error Creating iHistorian Server Manager - please check to see if Historain Client is correctly installed on your system", vbOKOnly, "test"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Create iHistorian server object'
    Set connectedServer = CreateObject("iHistorian_SDK.Server")

    'Check to see if the connection is established, else connect.'
    If CheckConnection = False Then connectedServer.Connect (HistServer)
    If CheckConnection = True Then

        'Browse the collector for tags.'
        Set MyTags = connectedServer.collectors.Item(HistCollector).BrowseTags(AdditionsOnly, SourceFilter, DescriptionFilter)

        'Loop all the tags from the collector'
        For Each Tag In MyTags.Item
            'INSERT CODE TO DO FOR EACH TAG HERE!'
            Debug.Print Tag.tagName
        Next

    End If

End Function



' make sure that we are connected to a server'
Public Function CheckConnection() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo errc

    If connectedServer Is Nothing Then
        CheckConnection = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Not connectedServer.Connected Then
        CheckConnection = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If connectedServer.ServerTime < CDate("1/1/1970") Then
        CheckConnection = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    CheckConnection = True
Exit Function

errc:
  CheckConnection = False
End Function
```

This works great.
But in my attempt to convert the same function over to C# i keep getting errors.

First i connect to my historian server, which is pretty painless.

```
            tsStatus.Text = "Connecting to " + HistServer;
            try
            {
                connectedServer = new iHistorian_SDK.Server();
                connectedServer.Connect(HistServer);
                tsStatus.Text = "Connected to " + HistServer;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print("Server connection threw exception: " + ex);
                tsStatus.Text = "Failed connecting to " + HistServer;
            }
```

My status label before i try to connect:

[image: Before Connection]

My status label after i try to connect:

[image: After connection]

After the connection is established, I would like to be able to do something like what i've done in VBA.

```
Set MyTags = connectedServer.collectors.Item(HistCollector).BrowseTags(AdditionsOnly, SourceFilter, DescriptionFilter)
```

My c# attempt goes as follows

```
            iHistorian_SDK.TagRecordset MyTags;
            MyTags = new iHistorian_SDK.TagRecordset();

            MyTags = connectedServer.Collectors.Item("SVNF-IFIX-SCA01_iFIX").BrowseTags(false, "*", "*");
```

[image: Error]

Does anyone know how I can come around this, or if it's even possible in C# to browse tags with the same methode of the collector object.

I've seen [this](https://youtube.com/watch?v=wi5q9Ava_Bc) video a few times so I would assume it's possible, they just skip the code where they actually browse tags.

Thanks in advance
/T

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis in VBA is an indexer. Try to replace `.Collectors.Item.("...")` with `.Collectors.Item.["..."]`

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint and inspect the `Collectors`object. Also figure out what type `Items`is.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source code for the video link you provided (I.e. The client SDK sample), they aren't using the collectors to query the tags.

cmdBrowseTags_Click is using the ITags "Query" method to 'Browse Tags'.

Here is the GE provided help doco example included in "iHistClientAccessAPI.chm":

```
TagQueryParams query = new TagQueryParams();
List<Tag> list = new List<Tag>(), temp = null;

query.Criteria.TagnameMask = "*";

// simple query
connection.ITags.Query(ref query, out list);

// paged query
list.Clear();
query.PageSize = 100; // return at most 100 results per request
while (connection.ITags.Query(ref query, out temp))
  list.AddRange(temp);
list.AddRange(temp);
```

I prefer something like this (includes the server connection for completeness):

```
ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(
new ConnectionProperties
{
    ServerHostName = "MyHistorianHostName",
    Username = "MyUserName",
    Password = "MyPassword",
    ServerCertificateValidationMode = CertificateValidationMode.None
});

serverConnection.Connect();

if (serverConnection.IsConnected())
{
    List<Tag> tagList = new List<Tag>();
    TagQueryParams tagQueryParams = new TagQueryParams
    {
        Criteria = new TagCriteria { TagnameMask = "*" }, // Wilcard, get all tags.
        Categories = Tag.Categories.All, // Change this to Basic fo mimimal info.
        PageSize = 100 // The batch size of the while loop below..
    };

    bool isQuery = true;
    while (isQuery)
    {
        isQuery = serverConnection.ITags.Query(ref tagQueryParams, out var tags);
        tagList.AddRange(tags);
    }

    // At this point, tagList contains a list of all tags that matched your wildcard filter.
    // To filter to a specific collector, you could then do something like:
    var collectorTagList = tagList.Where(t => t.CollectorName == "MyCollector");
}
```

Goodluck :)

Comment: I would assume this method only finds tags that are allready added to the Histroian server. The other BrowseTags methode on the Collector object finds all tags from the collector added or not added to Historian, I'm fairly sure this methode is equal to the "Search Historian Tag Database" within Historian Administrator where I would like to use the "Add Tags From Collector" browse methode.